# how to set the expiry time for redis cache in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, spring-data-redis

Hi I want to add an expiry time to the redis cache.

```
I have added spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=1m.
```

, but its not working.

I am using Jedis connection factory , for connection

please some thing , new to Redis.
Tried to create some beans as I got from google, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

To add an expiry time to Redis cache in Spring Boot, you can set the "spring.cache.redis.time-to-live" property in the application.properties file as you have done. This property specifies the default time-to-live for cache entries.

However, there are a few things to check if it's not working as expected:

1. Ensure that you have the Spring Boot Redis dependency in your pom.xml or build.gradle file.
2. Check if the Redis cache is enabled by adding the @EnableCaching annotation to your Spring Boot application class.
3. Check if the RedisConnectionFactory is properly configured. In your case, you are using JedisConnectionFactory. You can create a bean for the RedisConnectionFactory as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        // set the Redis server host and port
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }
```

5. Ensure that the RedisTemplate is properly configured. You can create a bean for RedisTemplate as follows:

```java
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        // set the key and value serializer
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

Note that in the above example, I'm using the GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer for serializing the values. You can change this to any other serializer that suits your needs.

Once you have the RedisConnectionFactory and RedisTemplate beans configured properly, Spring Boot should automatically apply the time-to-live property to the cached values.

If the issue still persists, you can try setting the TTL for a specific cache using the @Cacheable annotation as follows:

```
@Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "#key", unless = "#result == null", cacheManager = "cacheManager", cacheManagerCustomizers = MyCacheManagerCustomizer.class)
public Object getCachedData(String key) {
    // your code to retrieve the data from the database or any other source
}
```

In the above example, I have set the TTL for the "myCache" cache using the MyCacheManagerCustomizer class. You can implement this class to customize the cache manager as per your requirements.

I hope this helps you to add an expiry time to Redis cache in your Spring Boot application.

Comment: Thank you, its informative. But it still not working. Can you also providde the code for cacheManager = "cacheManager", cacheManagerCustomizers = MyCacheManagerCustomizer.class.